# Slicing of ndarrays over array boundaries

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

### Question:

given a ndarray:

```
In [2]: a
Out[2]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
```

I look for a routine giving me:

```
array([7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```

E**x.:** Starting at index 8, crossing the array boundarie and stopping at index 2 (included)
If I use slicing, I (of course) get:

```
In [3]: a[-3:2]
Out[3]: array([], dtype=int64)
```

### A possible answer:

Is to use the roll function.

```
In [5]: np.roll(a,3)[:5]
Out[5]: array([7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```

### What I look for:

What I do not like concerning this one, is that it is not as straightforward as slicing. So I look for something like:

```
In [6]: a.xxx[-3:2]
```

A syntax similar to this one exists for example in [pandas.DataFrame.iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html). Thank you very much in advance!

Note: iloc, does not do what I want. I just reffered to the syntax (which i like). Thanks for the comment, cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ

Comment: Even `.iloc[-3:2]` will give you an empty dataframe/series. What is it you want?

Comment: not sure what you mean by roll not being as straightforward? looks pretty compact to me

Comment: Check `np.take`.  It has modes like clip and wrap, but I haven't played with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## use `np.arange()`

3 years after asking this questing, this just popped into my head ...

```
>>> a = np.arange(10)
>>> a
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> a[np.arange(-3, 2)]
array([7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 3):

There isn't any slicing mechanism in python/numpy which automatically wraps around lists/arrays (as circular containers) as you seem to be looking for, so really the only way to do this is using functions. What you're doing with `roll` is nice and compact, even if it isn't as idiomatic as you like. Below, I've outlined a couple of (slightly more) idiomatic/pythonic solutions, which do the same thing.

**Option 1**
`np.take` based on [hpaulj's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48659161/slicing-of-ndarrays-over-arrauy-boundaries#comment84316335_48659161):

```
np.take(a, range(len(a) - 3, len(a) + 2), mode='wrap')
array([7, 8, 9, 0, 1])
```

---

**Option 2**
`islice`ing a `cycle` object:

```
from itertools import islice, cycle

list(islice(cycle(a), len(a) - 3, len(a) + 2))
[7, 8, 9, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not nearly as beautiful as coldspeeds solution or rolling, but

```
def over_edge_slicing(arr, start, end):
    return np.append(arr[start:], arr[:end])

a = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
print(over_edge_slicing(a, -3, 2))
```

would be another way to write this. However, you lose generality (you cant use this to slice from index 2-4 for example).